# PhantomJS throwing errors intermittently in JENKINS - Connection refused etc

Tags: ruby, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, capybara

I am getting the following errors in `Jenkins` very intermittently, the most recent of which is posted below. I have never seen this issue before. Some Developers push some `CSS` changes with `CSS3` and that is when I started getting the errors. I am using `phantomjs version - 1.9.8`. Any ideas?

```
Connection refused - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 8910 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
      /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:879:in `initialize'
      /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:879:in `open'
      /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:879:in `block in connect'
      /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:91:in `block in timeout'
      /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:101:in `call'
      /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:101:in `timeout'
      /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:878:in `connect'
      /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
      /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
      /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:1375:in `request'
```

Comment: Selenium Standalone server need to update on selenium hub. I think machine also update firefox and other browser too.

Comment: Selenium Standalone server needs to update in Jenkins? if it's to which version? We are running phantomjs in Jenkins not firefox....

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are facing this error everytime, then you need to update Selenium Standalone server on Jenkins.

if you are facing this issue intermittently, then you can try with restarting phantomjs also

```
def restart_phantomjs
        puts "-> Restarting phantomjs: iterating through capybara sessions..."
        session_pool = Capybara.send('session_pool')
        session_pool.each do |mode,session|
          msg = "  => #{mode} -- "
          driver = session.driver
          if driver.is_a?(Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver)
            msg += "restarting"
            driver.restart
          else
            msg += "not poltergeist: #{driver.class}"
          end
          puts msg
        end
      end
      module_function :restart_phantomjs
 end
```

Comment: You mentioned " then you need to update Selenium Standalone server on Jenkins."  Can you please explain me little more details about how to update Selenium Standalone server in Jenkins ???